# Subir volumen en una aplicacion de flutter en IOS via bluetooth

Tags: ios, flutter

he creado una aplicación móvil usando flutter y cuando debugueo en ios no puedo subir el volumen via bluetooth(manual mente si puedo) con unas bocinas. Esto solo me pasa en ios y he probado en android y no me ocurre esto. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale es-MX)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: No entiendo lo de **"subir el volumen via bluetooth"** manualmente me imagino que es con los botones de volumen del iPhone?

Comment: tengo unas bocinas que se conectan via bluetooth y me permiten subir y bajar el volumen y se ve reflejado en la app, pero cuando las uso en mi app en ios no hay ningun cambio de volumen usando mis bocinas, pero si lo hago con otra app, por ejemplo youtube si me deja o se ve reflejado el cambio de volumen

Comment: pero en android si funciona correctamente el cambio de volumen.

Comment: Tienes en el `.plist` el permiso de uso del bluetooth?

Comment: si, pero no funciono